# R - subsetting DF using with() and by()

Tags: r

Today is my first day on R - your advise will go a long way.

I am trying to create an aggregated view of users based on bookings activity.

Extract unique CustID in the bookings table. Create new DF for customer.

```
customer <- with(BookingsDF,data.frame(CustID=sort(unique(CustID))))
```

Add to each CustID in the customer table, the number of times they have transacted.

```
customer <- cbind(customer, NumberOrders = with(BookingsDF, 
  as.numeric (by (id, CustID, function(x) length(unique(x))))))
```

This generates an error message

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 373545, 391910

This doesn't make sense - how could the 2 queries output differing lengths? Considering that the first query extracts unique CustID, and the second query extracts the number of times each unique CustID has booked.

Thank you.

FINAL: Thanks for the help. I've updated the code to:

```
customer <- booked.dt[,{
  FirstPurchaseDate = .SD[which.min(CreatedDate)]
  LastPurchaseDate = .SD[which.max(CreatedDate)]
  NumberOrders = .N
  TotalAmount = sum(Price)
} , by = CustID]
```

Unfortunately, this took a long time to process. So I had to do the manipulation through SQL, and then uploaded the aggregated data to R.

Comment: The output from `by` would be a `list`

Answer (score 1):

There are many packages that offer solutions to this problem; I prefer `data.table`.  The basic idea is to split, calculate, and rejoin.  Declare a `data.table` and then calculate number of rows for each unique customer ID and store that in `customer`.

In this example, try this

```
library(data.table)
bookings.DT <- data.table(BookingsDF)
customer <- bookings.DT[,.N,by="CustID"]
```

and you should see a table of `CustID` and `N` in `customer`.  This assumes that the data are in long format.  If not, see `reshape2`